# Get element by Id in HTML DOM

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

i am trying go get content of certain `div` 
the html structure is something like this:

```
<div id="event-pane" class="class1">
   <div id="e170923" class="class2">
   <div id="e170948" class="class2">
   <div id="e170923" class="class2">
```

i am trying to get the div its `id="exxxxxx"` while xxxxxx is $event_id

i am using file_get_contants and DOM
here is my code:

```
<?php

    $event_id = $_GET['eventId'];

    //Get the url
    $url = "static/section35.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html
    if($html) {
    $divs = $doc->getElementById('e. $event_id, 0');

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody');

    $toRemove = array();

    // gather a list of tbodys to remove
    foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'desktop') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;    

            foreach($elements as $el)
      if((strpos($el->nodeValue, 'Recommended') !== false) && !in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
        $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;  

    // remove them
    foreach($toRemove as $tbody)
      $tbody->parentNode->removeChild($tbody);

    echo str_replace(array('style="display: none;','</h3><table','http://www.drakulastream.eu'),array('', '<table',''),$doc->saveHTML());
}
  else {
        echo "<center><h3 style='color:#003366;'>There are no events today</h3></center>";
           }
?>
```

i don't know what is wrong with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've just mis-typed the selector.  Should be like this:

```
$divs = $doc->getElementById('e' . $event_id);
```

Comment: worked now but getting all `div` that have the exxxxxx and not selecting only the one with e $event_id why?